# SPARQL query on rdf:resource

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, jena, owl

Suppose I want to retrieve the names of all elements in the periodic table with a standard state of `'gas'`. Here are what I believe are the relevant portions of the .owl file…

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID='StandardState'>
    <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType='Collection'>
        <StandardState rdf:ID='state_unknown'/>
        <StandardState rdf:ID='gas'/>
        <StandardState rdf:ID='solid'/>
        <StandardState rdf:ID='liquid'/>
    </owl:oneOf>
</owl:Class>
```

…example of an `Element` listing with `StandardState` `'gas'`, of course there are many more, but of the same format…

```xml
<Element rdf:ID="He">
    <name rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">helium</name>
    <symbol rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">He</symbol>
    <atomicNumber rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">2</atomicNumber>
    <atomicWeight rdf:datatype="&xsd;float">4.002602</atomicWeight>
    <group rdf:resource="#group_18"/>
    <period rdf:resource="#period_1"/>
    <block rdf:resource="#p-block"/>
    <standardState rdf:resource="#gas"/>
    <color rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">colourless</color>
    <classification rdf:resource="#Non-metallic"/>
    <casRegistryID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">7440-59-7</casRegistryID>
</Element>
```

I know how to query when what I ultimately want is linked to a XSD primitive, like `^^xsd:string`, but when what I'm querying against is an `rdf:resource` I'm confused as to how to proceed.

Comment: You should keep in mind that `rdf:resource` is not something that actually occurs in an RDF model. It's just an XML attribute name that can occur as part of a property element or a resource description element. Its value is a URI reference, and _that_ is what you should query on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You query for non-literals the same way that you query for literals:  by writing graph patterns to match against them.  In this case you can do something like:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org/periodic-table#>
SELECT ?element 
WHERE { 
  ?element ex:standardState ex:gas .
}
```